# find the factorization for a compex polynomial

Tags: analysis, polynomials, factoring

I have a question about finding the factorization for the complex polynomial:
$P(z)=z^{10}-z^9+z-1$. It is easy if $z \in \mathbb{R}, P(z)=(z^9-1)(z+1)$. However, I am not sure if this is true for $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Thanks!

Comment: It's just as true for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Distributivity, commutativity and associativity work the same, and that's all you need for that factorization. Note however that that's *not* the *irreducible* factorization of $P(z)$. Also, as a side note, you have the signs reversed between the two terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And this is exactly my point. How can we find irreducible factorization for P(z)?

Comment: Find the roots of $z^9+1=0$ and $z-1=0$.

Comment: In $\mathbb C$, irreducible factors will be linear. So you should get $10$ factors if you persist.